# Can anyone confirm if http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/attributes/terraform is a real ec2 meta-data endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, openai-api

I was recently testing ChatGPT on terraform scripts and came across something that I can't tell if it's a GPT "cannon fodder" or if this is an undocumented feature.

On a trained ChatGPT session I input:

> generate a bash script that can use random_pet resources from terraform

And this was the output:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Download metadata for the random_pet resource from the Terraform state file
metadata=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/attributes/terraform)

# Parse the metadata and extract the value of the "id" attribute
id=$(echo $metadata | jq -r '.random_pet_generator_id')

# Use the value of the "id" attribute in your Bash script
echo "Hello, $id!"
```

This looked bogus to me:

> `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/attributes/terraform`

Until I read about [Referring to Alternate Provider Configurations](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#referring-to-alternate-provider-configurations)

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why it will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin), I'm pretty sure that's not a real endpoint but hidden features are always a possibility. I ended up with:

**foo.tf**

```
  # Enables access to instance tags from the instance metadata service.
  metadata_options {
    instance_metadata_tags = "enabled"
    http_endpoint          = "enabled"
  }

  # Apply tags to the resources during launch (does not include default_tags)
  dynamic "tag_specifications" {
    for_each = toset(["instance", "volume", "network-interface"])
    content {
      resource_type = tag_specifications.key
      tags = {
        baz = random_pet.generator.id
      }
    }
  }
```

**bar.sh**

```bash
BAZ_TAG=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/baz)
```

I'm really curious how ChatGPT derived that endpoint. It definitely makes mistakes sometimes but even the mistakes are based on some element of truth.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `terraform` value in EC2 metadata. For the valid values please check [Instance metadata categories - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html).